# Null textboxs on subform stopping VB until parent choice is made

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting a runtime error

> Run-Time error 2427 You entered an expression that has no value.

I know why I am getting it I 
just dont know how to fix it. `ctrl1` and `ctrl2` are on a subform and are two text boxes that do some `If` statements 
on the form after this is ran so the text boxes are null or dont even have data yet. They are blank on the subform.

Here is my code:

```
Dim ctrl1 As Control
Dim ctrl2 As Control

Set ctrl1 = Me.Parent.frmRequirementsSubform.Form.txtSumOfCompleted
Set ctrl2 = Me.Parent.frmRequirementsSubform.Form.txtTotalRequirementsNeeded


If ctrl1 = ctrl2 Then
    Call SetLevel(cboArea, txtEmpID, txtDateFunctionCompleted)
End If
```

Here is the Function it is calling...

```
    Function SetLevel(lngFuncID As Long, lngEmpID As Long, varDateCompleted As Variant)

 Dim lngPosID As Long
 Dim lngEmpPosID  As Long
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strCriteria As String

 strCriteria = "EmpID = " & lngEmpID

 If DCount("*", "tblEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 8 Then
     lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblLevel", "Position = ""Operator 5""")

 ElseIf DCount("*", "tblEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 7 Then
     lngPosID = 0
    Exit Function
 ElseIf DCount("*", "tblEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 6 Then
     lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblLevel", "Position = ""Operator 4""")

 ElseIf DCount("*", "tblEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 5 Then
      lngPosID = 0
   Exit Function
 ElseIf DCount("*", "tblEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 4 Then
     lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblLevel", "Position = ""Operator 3""")

 ElseIf DCount("*", "tblEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 3 Then
      lngPosID = 0
   Exit Function
 ElseIf DCount("*", "tblEmployeeFunctions", _
      strCriteria & " And (FuncID = 1 Or FuncID = 2)") = 2 Then
      lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblLevel", "Position = ""Operator 2""")

 ElseIf lngFuncID = 1 Or lngFuncID = 2 Then
     lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblLevel", "Position = ""Operator 1""")
 End If

 'Debug.Print "lngPosID: " & lngPosID

 If lngPosID > 0 Then

      lngEmpPosID = Nz(DMax("EmpPosID", "tblEmployeeLevel"), 0) + 1
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblEmployeeLevel(EmpPosID, EmpID, PosID, DateAchieved) " & _
           "VALUES(" & lngEmpPosID & "," & lngEmpID & "," & lngPosID & "," & _
             IIf(IsNull(varDateCompleted), "NULL", "#" & Format(varDateCompleted, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#") & ")"

       CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
 End If
```

End Function

Comment: I suppose it's good that you "know why" you're getting the error, but please share.  You are asking for help solving the problem, but don't give enough detail.  Tell us 1) what line the error is occurring on and 2) all the details of why it is happening.

Comment: I recommend using a breakpoint to stop and trace through the code to find precisely what line the error is occurring on.  You're getting a bunch of good advice from others, but they are largely guessing.  Coding is just as much about perfecting debugging skills as it is fixing the errors.

Comment: I can raise this error if I use a Control-Source`  with a number as criteria but providing a string as criteria `=Dlookup("field","table","id = a")`. So what is the source of the control that raises the error. You can find out wich control is wrong by setting `If ctrl1 = ctrl1 Then` or the opposite `If ctrl2 = ctrl2 Then`. If error vanishes the other control is guilty.. Also update your question with the addiional infos from your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function SetLevel(lngFuncID As Long, lngEmpID As Long, varDateCompleted As Variant)

  Dim lngPosID As Long
  Dim lngEmpPosID  As Long
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim strCriteria As String

  strCriteria = "EmpID = " & lngEmpID

  If DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 8 Then
      lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 5""")

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 7 Then
      lngPosID = 0

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 6 Then
      lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 4""")

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 5 Then
       lngPosID = 0

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 4 Then
      lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 3""")

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 3 Then
       lngPosID = 0

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", _
       strCriteria & " And (FuncID = 1 Or FuncID = 2)") = 2 Then
       lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 2""")

  ElseIf lngFuncID = 1 Or lngFuncID = 2 Then
      lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 1""")
  End If

  If lngPosID > 0 Then

     lngEmpPosID = Nz(DMax("EmpPosID", "tblMetalShopEmployeeLevel"), 0) + 1

     strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMetalShopEmployeeLevel(EmpPosID, EmpID, PosID, DateAchieved) " & _
            "VALUES(" & lngEmpPosID & "," & lngEmpID & "," & lngPosID & "," & _
              IIf(IsNull(varDateCompleted), "NULL", "#" & Format(varDateCompleted, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") & "#") & ")"

        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the controls are on the subform, just reference them straight out, `Me.TextBox1` no need to crawl up to `Me.Parent.SubForm.Form.TextBox1`

Comment: This assumes that the code is running on the same subform as the controls.  How do you assume that?  Is this also an answer to keep the error from happening or just other coding advice?

Answer (score 0):

If I have to guess you are using somewhere a function which doesnt allow **Null** values. @C Perkins is right we need more details about the error.
But you can make a check in your code if the textboxes are **Null**, and if not execute the code.

```
If IsNull(ctrl1) or IsNull(ctrl2) Then
   ExitSub
Else
   'Do Stuff
End If
```

Comment: If this was a Null issue, there should be no error.  For most logical operations, null values result in False.  That would be the case with the equality operator, so the if statement would simply fail without error.  It is more likely that the subform itself is not fully initialized when there are no records, so that the reference to the particular control is not valid.

Comment: He also calls the Sub `SetLevel()` if he passes here a **Null** value it can result in error. For example if the `txtDateFunctionCompleted` has a `CDate()`. And `CDate(Null)` resolves in an error. And my hint was, that he should check for **Null** values.

Comment: Okay, but the two control variables that are tested in the if statement are not passed as arguments to the function, so once again testing for Null in `ctrl1` and `ctrl2` will not resolve the error.  Your hint might be useful, but it does not really answer the central question which has to do with the error.  Many times code that is shared could use pages of hints and advice, but it's best to focus on the question at hand.  That's why I pointed out that Null values are likely not the cause of the error.

Comment: You are right, but that was the best one could do out of the description. There are to much information missing.

Answer (score 0):

First, `frmRequirementsSubform` must be the name of the subform *control* (could be different from the name of the subform).

Then, insert some lines to show the values, and tell us what you see:

```
Debug.Print "ctrl1: >" & ctrl1.Value & <", ctrl2: >" & ctrl2.Value & "<"
If ctrl1.Value = ctrl2.Value Then
    Debug.Print "cboArea: >" & cboArea & "<, txtEmpID: >" & txtEmpID & "<,  txtDateFunctionCompleted: >" & txtDateFunctionCompleted & "<"
    Call SetLevel(cboArea, txtEmpID, txtDateFunctionCompleted)
End If
```

To compare also *Null* values, use for text:

```
If Nz(ctrl1.Value, "") = Nz(ctrl2.Value, "") Then
```

or, for numeric:

```
If Nz(ctrl1.Value, 0) = Nz(ctrl2.Value, 0) Then
```

**Edit**:

To check also for empty objects:

```
If Not (ctrl1 Is Nothing Or ctrl2 Is Nothing) Then
    If Nz(ctrl1.Value, 0) = Nz(ctrl2.Value, 0) Then
```

Comment: Gustav, I get an error 2427 you entered an expression that has no value.  I tried your debug.print and it stops at the If ctrl1.Value = ctrl2.Value Then line. I run the VB on a subforms after update and after I choose a selection from a combo box then that's the criteria for the Parent.frmRequirementsSubform text boxes and that's why I think I'm getting theres no data because there is none yet.

Comment: That makes sense. Perhaps you can check for the controls not being _Nothing_. See edited answer please.

Comment: As I said in comments on Strawberryshrub's answer, the error is likely happening *before* the variables `ctrl1` and `ctrl2` can be checked for Nothing or their values inspected. Before recordsets are loaded or if there are no records in the RecordSource, some controls are not accessible or some properties are inaccessible.  This is different than the properties just being Nothing or Null, rather it is invalid to even access the properties.  I did not post an answer because I was waiting on OP to give more detail about **the exact line** the error was occurring on before throwing out guesses.

Comment: Gustav, I tried your not nothing and it wouldn't let the into in my other form load which tells me the line Call SetLevel(cboArea, txtEmpID, txtDateFunctionCompleted) Ran. So what I did was commented that line out and put a message box there and tried and the message box came up. So the Not nothing isn't working...

Comment: We could try this a different way. I have a subform frmRequirementsSubform and on this subform it populates records mainly a date field named txtDateCompleted with a control source [ReqDateCompleted]. When every date field has data I need to run the Call SetLevel(cboArea, txtEmpID, txtDateFunctionCompleted) that's on a subform named frmEmployeeFunctionsSubform.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow this. Have in mind, please, that I don't have your application.

Comment: The fact that a message box popped up with Gustav's "not nothing" check means that the variables `ctrl1` and `ctrl2` are successfully being set--they have valid controls. That indicates that the error is **inside** the SetLevel() function for which you have not shared the code. I'm doing my best to provide good debugging guidance, but feel like everyone is just guessing and randomly trying code without systematically drilling down to find the problem. Best of luck... once again, I suggest looking into the SetLevel function! Use breakpoints, learn how to trace through the code, etc.

Comment: Ok, C Perkins I added the Function it calls in my post... Hope this helps!